# Can't save a Rails 4.2 array in Postgres array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to save an array of terms on each Dictionary model (I want to be able to search tags basically).  So terms=["apple", "pear", "fruit"] could be one example of a term array I'm trying to save on each instance of a Dictionary model.  Previously, terms was a serialized text column.  I then changed it to try and take advantage of the Postgres array datatype as follows.  When I try to update a model (e.g., dictionary_example1.terms = ["fruit", "pineapple"] followed by a call to save), all that is stored is an empty array [].  What am I doing wrong?

**Model.rb**

```
class Dictionary < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :terms, Array

end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "clinical_trials", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "terms",             array: true
  end
```

**migration**

```
class ChangeTermsToArray < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      change_column :dictionaries, :terms, "varchar[] USING (string_to_array(terms, ','))"
  end
end
```

Comment: I thought serialized columns should be in a text field?

Comment: Thanks, removing the "serialize" from the model did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) in ActiveRecord is used for serialization of ruby objects into string in order to persist ruby object in database. The most popular is YAML serializer. Rails 4 has a builtin support of Postgresql arrays [since 4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes), so we do not need to set string serializer for array attribute in model.