# Can't persist array in a Postgres column using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, carrierwave, postgresql-9.4

I know this question may sound duplicated, but none of the solutions I've found actually solved my problem.

I have a model named pet with photos column, here's my schema:

```
t.string "photos", default: [], array: true
```

I'm not using the serialize method in my class because a lot of other [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357941/cant-save-a-rails-4-2-array-in-postgres-array-column) confirmed that it's not necessary.

Here's my object:

```
#<Pet id: 9, name: nil, age: nil, vaccinated: nil, male: nil, pet_description: nil, additional_info: nil, size: nil, neutered: nil, classified_id: nil, created_at: "2016-10-21 23:36:37", updated_at: "2016-10-21 23:55:50", kind: nil, photos: []>
```

No matter I do, I cannot persist a new photo array:

```
UPDATE "pets" SET "updated_at" = $1, "photos" = $2 WHERE "pets"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", 2016-10-21 23:51:30 UTC], ["photos", "{}"], ["id", 9]]
```

I've already tried several ways of persisting, [like](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14763):

```
model.array << element
model.array_will_change!
model.save!
```

or even ([like this guy suggested](http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/28/rails-4-and-postgres-arrays/), and this [other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283854/new-data-not-persisting-to-rails-array-column-on-postgres) as well):

```
update_attributes locations: locations + [ place ]
```

and none of them seems to work.

Using Postgres command line I was able to save and update and array with no problems, but this issue seems to be related to active record.

activerecord (5.0.0.1)
postgres (9.6.0.0)

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: What is the result when you do `model.photos << 'test'; model.save`